# iterating over an Ajax call and storing all data in object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, object, caching

I'm trying to learn angular and I'm stumped.  In my factory I am hitting this API to collect all the rounds data so I can store it in an object. Since there are 20 rounds I'd prefer to only hit this API once and then somehow cache the results as well. I have it working if I make an individual call to a specific round and return the data, but I want to collectively add any data from each link into one big object I can use from there on out. Thanks for any help. Here's my code so far:

Factory:

```
angular.module('dashFactory', []).factory('dashboard', ['$http', function($http) {
var allRounds = {};
return {

getRounds: function() {
    for (var i=1; i<21; i++){
        var url = 'http://footballdb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/event/world.2014/round/' + i + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        $http.jsonp(url).then(function(result){
            allRounds["round" + i] = result;
        });
    }
    return allRounds;
}
/*  Below works BUT I have to call each function individually in controller
//getRound1: function() {
   var url = 'http://footballdb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/event/world.2014/round/1?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
   return $http.jsonp(url);
}, 
getRound2: function() {
   var url = 'http://footballdb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/event/world.2014/round/2?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
   return $http.jsonp(url);
},
*/
};
}]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('dashCtrl', []).controller('dashController', function($scope, dashboard){
var allData = {};
$scope.allData = allData;

$scope.getData = function(){
    dashboard.getRounds().then(function(data){
        allData = data;
        console.log(allData);
});
};

/* Below is what I have been doing invidually, but I don't want to call 20 functions!
dashboard.getRound1().success(function(data){
    allData["round1"] = data.games[0];
     console.log(allData);
});
dashboard.getRound2().success(function(data){
    allData["round2"] = data.games[1];
     console.log(allData);
});
*/

});
```

Comment: Well... one problem is that `i` is declared outside of the scope of your success callback. I'm assuming there's only one key in your object when it returns: `round20`? Why can't you get all of them at once instead of making 20 AJAX requests?

Answer (score 0):

First, make one request to get all 20. There's no reason you should have to make 20 requests. A caching strategy I like to use is as follows:

```
app = angular.module('app', [])
  .service('Round', function($log, $q, $http) {
    var rounds;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return {
      getRounds: function(fromServer) {
        if(rounds && !fromServer) {
          deferred.resolve(rounds);
        } else {
          $http.get('http://footballdb.herokuapp.com/api/v1/event/world.2014/rounds')
            .success(function(results) {
              rounds = results;
              deferred.resolve(rounds);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
              $log.error('Could not get rounds: ' + error);
              deferred.reject(error);
            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  })
```

Define controllers similar to this:

```
app.controller('ACtrl', function($scope, Round) {
  Round.getRounds().then(function(rounds) {
    $scope.rounds = rounds;
  });
})

app.controller('BCtrl', function($scope, Round) {
  Round.getRounds().then(function(rounds) {
    $scope.rounds = rounds;
  });
});
```

This example will only make one AJAX request for the runtime of your application (Unless someone refreshes the page of course). The `rounds` object available in all your controllers is the same as in your service. Making modifications to it will change it in your other controllers. Optionally, request the rounds from the server again by calling `getRounds(true)`. Because the promise is also shared across controllers/directives, every time you request rounds from the server, all rounds will be refreshed in your controllers.